# CIImage properties are lost when running an image through a custom CIFilter

Tags: ios, image-processing, core-image

When I use predefined CIFilter objects, the properties from the input CIImage are preserved in the output CIImage.

For example...

```
// 1. Gamma adjustment.  After the following, gammaAdjusted image has the same properties as inputImage.
NSNumber * gammaExponent = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.2];
[_gammaAdjustFilter setValue:croppedImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
[_gammaAdjustFilter setValue:gammaExponent forKey:@"inputPower"];
CIImage * gammaAdjustedImage = _gammaAdjustFilter.outputImage;
```

Then I run the image through my custom CIFilter.

```
// 2. Difference of Gaussians.  
_dogFilter.rad1 = 1.0;
_dogFilter.rad2 = 2.0;
_dogFilter.inputImage = gammaAdjustedImage;
CIImage * dogImage = _dogFilter.outputImage;
```

After this call, dogImage.properties is NULL, and it even crashes when trying to access it.  When debugging my implementation of the custom filter below, blur1 is the first returned CIImage where properties didn't persist into output.  I originally I thought that perhaps the properties were being lost by how I was applying the kernel, when it's actually the CIGaussianBlur filter.

> (lldb) po blur1.properties
>   error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0).
>   The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

```
-(CIImage *)outputImage
{

// Use the same input image both times.
[m_guassianBlurFilter setValue:self.inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];

// Configure the first blurred image.
NSNumber * rad1Number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.rad1];
[m_guassianBlurFilter setValue:rad1Number forKey:@"inputRadius"];
CIImage * blur1 = m_guassianBlurFilter.outputImage;

// Configure the second blurred image.
NSNumber * rad2Number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.rad2];
[m_guassianBlurFilter setValue:rad2Number forKey:@"inputRadius"];
CIImage * blur2 = m_guassianBlurFilter.outputImage;

// Now diff them using the kernel.
CIKernelROICallback roi = ^CGRect (int index, CGRect destRect) {
    if ( CGRectIsInfinite(destRect) ) {
        return CGRectNull;
    }
    else return destRect;
};

CIImage * DoG = [m_differenceKernel applyWithExtent:self.inputImage.extent roiCallback:roi arguments:@[blur1, blur2]];
return DoG;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try a different approach to obtain a difference of gaussians (DoG). It should faster than the one proposed and it works flawlessy.

```
- (CIImage *)makeDoG:(CIImage *)inputImage {
    CIFilter *gauss1 = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
    [gauss1 setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [gauss1 setValue:@(1) forKey:@"inputRadius"];

    CIImage *tmpImage = gauss1.outputImage;
    [gauss1 setValue:@(3.0) forKey:@"inputRadius"];
    CIImage *tmpImage2 = gauss1.outputImage;

    CIFilter *mixA = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISubtractBlendMode"];
    [mixA setValue:tmpImage2 forKey:@"inputBackgroundImage"];
    [mixA setValue:tmpImage forKey:@"inputImage"];

    CIFilter *invert = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorInvert"];
    [invert setValue:mixA.outputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];

    return invert.outputImage;
}
```